# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double(System.String, System.String)' method

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

```
  LocalPrecedentEntities _local = new LocalPrecedentEntities();
            SES1 ses1 = new SES1();
            var precedent =  from p in _local.Precedent__case_
                             where ses1.FindSES1(query.ToLower(), p.Query.ToLower()) < 80
                             select p;
            if (precedent.Count() <= 0)
            {
                var iSites = this.getSitesFromDB(query, queryType);
                return iSites;
            }
            else
            {
                var sites = new List<string>();
            foreach (var p in precedent)
            {

                var pSite = from r in _local.Result
                            where r.ResultId == p.ResultId
                            select r.SiteId;
                sites.AddRange(pSite);
            }
```

I got error like below. Where is the problem? Please someone can advise? Thanks.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double FindSES1(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: what line gives you this error?

Comment: here -  if (precedent.Count() <= 0)

Comment: wrong. Its here `FindSES1(query.ToLower(), p.Query.ToLower())`

Comment: Hi Aron. really? need to correct? please how? Thanks.

Comment: You can't. SES isn't a class that exists in SQL Server. You have to run it as a LinqToObjects query. Which means downloading the entire table. Just replace `_local.Precedent__case_` with `_local.Precedent__case_.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: Maybe you can _implement_ the `FindSES1` method's _logic_ in your `where` clause... could you show us its code?